# Export string to HTML file

Tags: javascript, python-2.7

Trying to write a string to a HTML file but am getting a syntax error on the third line 'pagetitle'. how can I properly export this? New to python and my notes aren't helping.

Writing in Python, exporting to HTML.

```
def paragraph_function(filename, pagetitle, textbody):
    output_file = file(filename)
    output_file.write('<html><head><title>'pagetitle'</title></head>')
```

Comment: What does it have to do with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You should concatenate the **pagetitle** to the string being written to the output file

```
output_file.write('<html><head><title>' + pagetitle + '</title></head>')
```

Comment: To avoid error it should also be str(pagetitle) or unicode(pagetitle)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def paragraph_function(filename, pagetitle, textbody):
  output_file = open(filename,'w+')
  data = '<html><head><title>'+pagetitle+'</title></head>'
  output_file.write(data)


pagetitle= 'page'
filename= 'out'
textbody = ''
paragraph_function(filename, pagetitle, textbody)
```